# Js styling, targeting an element by defining it's attribute?

Tags: javascript, html

I have spent some time creating this little Js snippet to create a char count. This is nested inside a textarea. ([JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9s6zr718/14/)). My issue is that I have no access to CSS, HTML, or Js/Jq root files stored on the server. I am however allowed to insert my own Js through a seperate page that will excecute on the target page. So I figured what the hey, I'll give it a go.

First I generated the character limit in Js tested and all worked fine, but then I tried to target the textarea with Js to style it. As well as dynamically create a div for the char count to be displayed and style that. BAM no result. After digging around in the debugger I noticed that there are two elements that might be causing the problem but I'm not sure.

```
<label for="desinp">
    Description
</label>

<textarea style="width: 417px; height: 237px;" class="required" id="desinp" name="desinp" maxlength="2500"> 
</textarea>
```

I noticed the `for="desinp` and the `id="desinp"` were identical. Would this cause conflict in the Js, if I don't define the attribute and target the attribute I want to target?

I would test it myself by pulling the label out, but I don't have access to the root HTML.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated. Many Thanks in advance...

Comment: The `for` attribute of a label is meant to be the same as the `id` attribute of a form element. That's just how it works.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up. But I'm still left with the issue of the code not working. The site is heavy on JS but I don't see any errors or warnings in the debgger... :(

Comment: We'll need to see a complete example in some way that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Would a user login and link to the page in question help?